# JavaScript, confusing syntax when declaring a variable

Tags: javascript, variables, syntax

I recently came across the following line of code in a JavaScript book that I am working through:

`var col = [], top, bottom;`

This is the first time I've encountered a variable seemingly being given three variables. Could someone explain what is happening in this line of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is simply a shorter version of this:

```
var col = [];
var top;
var bottom;
```

There is no real advantage/disadvantage of one style over the other, but [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) likes to have all `var` declarations in each scope combined (as you have in your question):

> In languages with block scope, it is usually recommended that
>   variables be declared at the site of first use. But because JavaScript
>   does not have block scope, it is wiser to declare all of a function's
>   variables at the top of the function. **It is recommended that a single
>   var statement be used per function**.

---

For a full explanation of why this is the case, you can have a look at the [ECMAScript spec](http://es5.github.com/#x12.2). Here's the relevant part of the grammar:

> *VariableStatement : `var` VariableDeclarationList `;`*
>
> *VariableDeclarationList : VariableDeclaration VariableDeclarationList `,` VariableDeclaration*
>
> *VariableDeclaration : Identifier Initialiser<sub>opt</sub>*

It's also worth noting that the commas used here are *not* the same as the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). It just happens to use the same character.

Comment: @Pablo - That's a matter of preference. I don't think either is clearer than the other, especially if the comma-separated version is written across multiple lines.

Comment: Clarity is relative. There are times when explicitly declaring each var one per line is far more clear, but there's also times when declaring some minor vars to be used later in the script line by line like normal would create 20 lines of clutter for no real clarity advantage. Not to mention the shorthand declaration can be used to communicate between developers that certain variables have a close relationship to each other, which can help greatly in clarity.

Comment: @James - Thanks for the very detailed answer! Also, this is the first I've heard of [link](http://www.jslint.com) -- something I'm sure will be a  great resource to me in the future. So thanks for that as well!

Comment: @JimboJonny - I'm glad that you mentioned the idea of developers communicating which variables have a close relationship to one another. That's a great way to think of it in my opinion, and I'll definitely be keeping it in mind in future code that I write.

Answer (score 4):

Read it as

```
var
    col = [],
    top,
    bottom;
```

Three variables are declared, but only one is initialized.

Answer (score 1):

This is general syntax of declaring multiple variables in `javascript`.
It says you are declaring three variables namely `col` , `top` , `bottom` , where `col` is of type `array`.
It's same as :

```
var col = [];
var top ;
var bottom;
```

Helpful links : 
 http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch04_02.htm
http://freewebdesigntutorials.com/javaScriptTutorials/jsArrayObject/declareAnArray.htm

Comment: Thanks for the answer and helpful links! I'll be checking those out first chance I get.

Answer (score 0):

This statement does not assign three values to col, it simply declares three variables and one of them is an array.