# Is the comma in a `var` statement an example of the comma operator?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Or in a `const` or `let` statement, for that matter.

For example, in this statement `const a = 0, b = 1;`, the equivalent code (completely same effect) would be:

```
const a = 0;
const b = 1;
```

But then, am I right to say that the comma in that statement is not the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)? Because if it was the comma operator, then `const a = 0, b = 1` should be equivalent to:

```
a = 0; // This already would throw a ReferenceError in strict mode
const b = 1;
```

Similarly, `var a, b, c;` should be to `a; b; var c;` if that comma indeed was the comma operator, but instead its effect is that of `var a; var b; var c;`.

Is my reasoning correct, or do I misunderstand the comma operator? I ask this because I've seen multiple articles giving statements like `var i = 0, j = 9;` as examples of the comma operator (that last one is from the MDN page), but I think that it's a different comma, in the same way that commas in function parameters and arrays are different from the comma operator.

Is it an example of the comma operator, or not?

Comment: No, it is not. It's part of the declaration syntax, not the expression syntax.  You have to enclose the initialization expressions in parentheses in order to have a comma be the expression comma.

Comment: Something that may help; on the same [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator): "Note that the comma in assignments such as the var statement may appear not to have the normal effect of comma operators because they don't exist within an expression. In the following example, a is set to the value of b = 3 (which is 3), but the c = 4 expression still evaluates and its result returned to console (i.e., 4). This is due to operator precedence and associativity."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10979370/1048572

Comment: Thank you, that clears it up. The top answer in the link by Bergi also mentions the annotated ES5 reference: https://es5.github.io/ , which I didn't know about.

Comment: Also with `let`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55788284/how-comma-operator-is-used-between-the-statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commas are used in quite a few places:

- expressions: `(x, y) + 1`
- declaration statements: `let x, y`
- function arguments: `foo(1,2,3)`
- array/object initializers: `[1,2,3]`
- destructuring patterns `[x, y] = a`

Of these, only the first one is the comma operator, others are... well, just commas (although sometimes they go by a fancy name "elision").

For the `let/const` statements specifically, the grammar is here: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations

Comment: "Elision" is specifically the grammar production for a comma or sequence of commas representing elided array elements; calling commas elisions in general is wrong, and an elision can consist of multiple commas.